# Gitlab-CI does not find PHPMD while running test

Tags: build, gitlab-ci, phpmd

I started to experiment with Gitlab-CI but i have some problems while running my builds. At this point i started to run PHPMD from the building using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
phpmd:
script:
-  /tmp/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd app/code/local text cleancode,codesize,design
```

All this is ok and the build is fired. The problem is that the build keeps failing:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.5.2 (adb8153) 
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.1 ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Starting service redis:latest ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Running on runner-42afea22-project-4-concurrent-0 via LINXAACC101...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/MyProject/Foo'...
Checking out a3e2b48f as development...
$ /tmp/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd app/code/local text cleancode,codesize,design
/builds/Dynalean/Tekenzeker.sh: line 22: /tmp/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd: No such file or directory
ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

This is strange since when i run the command on the commandline it runs like a charm:

> /tmp/phpmd/src/bin/phpmd /tmp/phpmd/src/main text
>   cleancode,codesize,design

For further debugging i set the PHPMD executable to 777 (the full directory) using `sudo chmod 777 -R /tmp/phpmd`. This also reflects on the executable:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7350 Oct 16 12:03 phpmd*

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you testing the command by running the command on the Gitlab CI Multirunner host? I.e. is the /tmp/phpmd folder located on the host OS?

I see that you are using the Docker executor with the default ruby:2.1 image. Unless you have linked in the /tmp/phpmd directory from somewhere else, the ruby:2.1 container will not contain any such folder.

Comment: The multirunner runs on the same host as the gitlab-ci application? And yes the phpmd is installed over there. Are there other options instead of Docker that are better etc? And where is it running from so i can link it if needed